# MySQL Trigger syntax for ordering based on user id

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, schema

I would like to create a trigger on the FRIENDS table so that friend pairs are ordered and there aren't duplicate entries with the same friends. The following trigger is throwing a syntax error at `BEGIN IF (:new.USER1_ID > :new.USER2_ID) ...`  -- how is this trigger supposed to be formatted?

```
CREATE TABLE USERS (
    USER_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    YEAR_OF_BIRTH INTEGER,
    MONTH_OF_BIRTH INTEGER,
    DAY_OF_BIRTH INTEGER,
    SSN INTEGER,
    EMAIL VARCHAR(100),
    PHONE INTEGER,
    PWD VARCHAR(100),
    ADDRESS VARCHAR(500),
    PRIMARY KEY(USER_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE FRIENDS (
    USER1_ID INTEGER,
    USER2_ID INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (USER1_ID) REFERENCES USERS(USER_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (USER2_ID) REFERENCES USERS(USER_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY(USER1_ID, USER2_ID),
    CHECK(USER1_ID!=USER2_ID)
);
 
 CREATE TRIGGER FRIENDS_TRIGGER
 BEFORE INSERT ON FRIENDS FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
 DECLARE TEMP INTEGER
     BEGIN
         IF (:new.USER1_ID > :new.USER2_ID) THEN
           SET TEMP = :new.USER1_ID
           SET :new.USER1_ID = :new.USER2_ID
           SET :new.USER2_ID = TEMP
         END IF
 END
 /
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems.  You need to terminate statements with semicolons, and so you also need to change the delimiter so the entire create trigger is treated as a single statement.  `:new` should also be `NEW.`  And you have an extra BEGIN thrown in there.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER FRIENDS_TRIGGER
BEFORE INSERT ON FRIENDS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE TEMP INTEGER;
    IF (NEW.USER1_ID > NEW.USER2_ID) THEN
        SET TEMP = NEW.USER1_ID;
        SET NEW.USER1_ID = NEW.USER2_ID;
        SET NEW.USER2_ID = TEMP;
    END IF;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: ':new should also be NEW.' - unless OP is actually using oracle - or attempting oracle syntax in mysql.